# ftp in script is asking password though the password is in script

Tags: linux, unix, ftp

Previously the below script have not asked password when execute but all of a sudden it is asking password. I have tried to pass the username, password and server name in single quotes but still it is asking password.

```
   #!/bin/ksh
   HOST=ftp.test.com
   USER=test
   PASSWD=test
   ftp  -A $USER@$HOST <<SCRIPT
   $PASSWD
   quit
```

Comment: If your remote host provides it, prefer `ssh` or `sftp` to plain `ftp` (since the password is transmitted in plain form)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use instead,

```
ftp ftp://$USER:$PASSWD@$HOST
```

Comment: When i user above one i got below error
ftp: Name or service not known
ftp: Can't connect or login to host `test'

My username is like test/test1

Please help me on this

Comment: I am sorry @Skynet same error i am getting eventhough i remove -A and placed as per your suggestion

Comment: @Revanth the syntax is same, so may be something else is doing problem

Comment: Yest..I am not getting wat is causing the issue. Please help me on this